# How to print file size in bytes to a .txt file

Tags: linux, unix

I use `ls -l` command to see all the file size in the folder. Can anybody help me how to output that in a `.txt` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a terminal and use the following command:

```
ls -l > yourfile.txt
```

http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/iodirection.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want to put *only* the size of some file `foo` in the text file `out.txt`, you would perhaps

```
 ls -l foo | awk '{print  $5}' > out.txt
```

and there are many other variants (e.g. using `cut` instead of `awk`, or using `stat` instead of `ls` etc).

In a shell script or on the terminal, you could assign that size to some variable `VAR` with e.g.

```
VAR=$(ls -l foo | awk '{print  $5}')
```

If you are statisfied with all the output of `ls` a plain redirection `ls -l foo > out.txt` is enough, as answered by others.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `stat(1)` directly:

```
stat -c '%s %n' *
```

Or if doing it recursively:

```
find /some/path -type f -printf '%s %f\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it use
    ls -l> yourfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *[du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du)* command:

```
du * > file.txt
```

*du* return the space usage of a file, so if you need all the file within a directory you must use *

Example:

```
$ cd /path/to/directory
$ du * > file.txt
```

or

```
$ du /path/to/directory/* > /path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Just realised this is pretty off-topic since the question was about redirects.**

I have no idea why `du` likes to display blocks instead of bytes.

Personally I think `ls -l $1 | awk '{ print $5 }'` is too much processing, and unreasonable if you expect graceful error handling.

For me, the easiest option is just compiling something more efficient:

$ `nano flsz.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f && (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) == 0)) {
      int size = ftell(f);
      fclose(f);
      fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", size);
    } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "0\n");
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "-1\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

$ `gcc -o /usr/bin/flsz flsz.c`

$ `flsz flsz.c`

`340`

$ `flsz /usr/bin/flsz > output.txt`

$ `cat output.txt`

`8972`